# WebStorm 9 TypeScript intellisense (code completion) fails

Tags: typescript, intellisense, webstorm

I have my external library imported with some class definitions. The intellisense works only partially, see below.

```
import BB = require('../services/BB');
var r = new BB.Model.Repository();
var name: string = r.name; // Ok, we've got intellisense here

var func = (repo) => { }; // No intellisense here -- ok of course
var func2 = (repo: BB.Model.Repository) => { }; // No intellisense -- why?
var func3 = function(repo: BB.Model.Repository) { }; // No intellisense -- why?
var func4: (r: BB.Model.Repository)=>void = function(repo): void { }; // No intellisense -- why?
var func5 = () => {
  var repo = new BB.Model.Repository();
  var name:string = repo.name; // Ok, we've got intellisense here
};
var func6 = (repo: any) => {
  var name: string = (<BB.Model.Repository>repo).name; // No intellisense here -- why?
};
```

What is the problem? Is there anything wrong with my library, or is it just WebStorm?

BTW the library export goes this way across a few files:

```
// BB.Model.Repository.ts
export = Repository;
class Repository { name: string; }

// BB.Model.ts
export import Repository = require("./BB.Model.Repository");

// BB.ts
export import Model = require ('./BB.Model');
```

Comment: I'd suggest creating a support ticket, providing the details (what Model.Repository looks like, how do you try to get intellisence, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reported the problem, an issue is created at JetBrains:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14844

**Update.** They say it's fixed in version 10.

Answer (score 0):

> import BB = require('../services/BB');

Will only work *just with the default TypeScript language service* if there is a file `/services/BB.ts`.  I suspect there is no such file and the intellisense you are getting is just some conincidental + unreliable awesome code analysis done by `Webstorm` same as it does for JavaScript. The intellisense for JavaScript is *never guranteed* to be reliable.

TypeScript probably doesn't have the type `BB.Model.Repository` in its type declaration space.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. However, the paths are ok, `tsc` also cries if I rename BB.ts, nothing changes if all the compiled .js files are deleted. Plus I had the same files and paths in Visual Studio and its intellisense works fine. It surely seems to be something with WebStorm.